# jellyfish vs pyjarowinkler

Tags: python, jaro-winkler

I am trying to use the Jaro-Winkler similarity distance to see if two strings are similar. I tried using both the libraries to compare the words `carol` and `elephant`.  The results are not similar:

```py
import jellyfish

jellyfish.jaro_winkler('Carol','elephant')
```

returns `0.4416666`, while

```py
from pyjarowinkler import distance

distance.get_jaro_distance('Carol','elephant')
```

returns `0.0` which makes more sense to me.

Is there a bug between the two libraries?

Comment: The implementations seem to be incompatible. `jellyfish.jaro_winkler('test', 'rest')` and `distance.get_jaro_distance('test', 'rest')` produce different outputs. I would find some third library to see which implementation is correct.

Comment: Just posted it here before somebody only reads the comment above. Please see may answer below. Jellyfish ist correct. I linked the original paper about jaro winkler distance.

Answer (score 7):

The Jellyfish implemenation is correct.

Carol and elephant didn't have a matching prefix. Therefore the Jaro-Winkler distance is equal to the Jaro distance in this Case. I calculated the Jaro distance by hand and found that the implementation of Jellyfish is correct. There is an online calculator, but the online calculator is also wrong. I also found some other implementations like in the python-Levenstein package, wich also implements the Jaro-Winkler distance, that validated my calculations. There is also an implemenatation on npm. If you like to compute the score by you own - you can find the paper [here](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED325505.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps worth noting that two different implementations in R seem to match the jellyfish version:

```
library(stringdist)
> 1 - stringdist("Elephant", "Carol", method = 'jw')
[1] 0.4416667

library(RecordLinkage)
> jarowinkler('Carol','elephant')
[1] 0.4416667
```